# VHDL equivalent of Verilog localparam

Tags: vhdl, verilog

I found the following statement in a verilog modul:

```
localparam str2="  Display Demo  ", str2len=16;
```

Seems to me that str2 is a string value but I wonder how this is processed in the following code snippet.

```
always@(write_base_addr)
    case (write_base_addr[8:7])//select string as [y]
    0: write_ascii_data <= 8'hff & (str1 >> ({3'b0, (str1len - 1 - write_base_addr[6:3])} << 3));//index string parameters as str[x]
    1: write_ascii_data <= 8'hff & (str2 >> ({3'b0, (str2len - 1 - write_base_addr[6:3])} << 3));
    2: write_ascii_data <= 8'hff & (str3 >> ({3'b0, (str3len - 1 - write_base_addr[6:3])} << 3));
    3: write_ascii_data <= 8'hff & (str4 >> ({3'b0, (str4len - 1 - write_base_addr[6:3])} << 3));
    endcase
```

Will the string value be convertet into a bit value first? Write_ascii_data is only 8 bits long, seems to me that it is too short for fully storing the end result of the case process. Is there any vhdl equivalent of localparam string ?

Comment: I find your question very unclear. It seems like you're asking multiple questions at once. And the final question about VHDL seems to come out of the blue. Please clarify and be more specific.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Verilog has no string types. A string literal gets converted to the equivalent ASCII bit vector, 8 bits per character. So str2 is a 128 bit vector parameter. The RHS expressions are shifting str2 to the left by some multiple of 8 bits, selecting one ASCII character.